# Getting a PHP Project Class and Function search Command to work in TextMate

Tags: php, textmate

I can't seem to get this to work..
http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/Howtos#PHPProjectFunctions

looks like there are missing settings, or I need to create the .tmCommand manually, which I don't even know where to start with..

anyone have a .tmCommand that will do this?

basically I am trying to access the classes and functions of my project when working in PHP in TextMate.

Answer (score 0):

The posted link seems to refer to an older version of TextMate. However, you could try a ctags-based solution instead, e.g. [TM Ctags](https://github.com/sbenhaim/tm-ctags-tmbundle).